# Formatação Data com Onchange Javascript

Tags: javascript

Estou com muitas dificuldades em fazer esse tipo de formatação no campo, se alguém puder me ajudar ficarei muito grato, bom, tenho um campo do formulário:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">        
        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2 form-label">
            {{Form::label('data', 'Data')}}
        </div>         
        <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-10 col-xs-10">            
            {{Form::date('data', null, ['class' => 'form-control'])}}
        </div>     
    </div>
```

A intenção é fazer esse campo na seguinte formatação, quando a pessoa digita 2 números o campo automaticamente coloca uma barra assim sucessivamente formando exatamente o tipo date, no entanto tem um detalhe, o campo permite que a pessoa use a tecla backspace para apagar qualquer caractere, sendo assim, não atrapalhando o campo do formato correto.

Alguém poderia me ajudar nessa função por favor? Ao menos me dá uma ideia já me ajuda muito, estou totalmente perdido e não sei por onde começar !
Grato desde já.

Comment: Um jeito fácil é usar `<input type= "date">`. Outras maneiras é utilizando algum plugin `jQuery`, por exemplo https://plugins.jquery.com/mask/

Comment: Obrigado por se dispor a ajudar caro amigo, no entanto o formato já está em date e não esta sendo muito recomendado por que não é suportado por todos os browsers, como citado pelo amigo lá em baixo.

Comment: Eu indico utilizar um plugin https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/ Input date não são suportados por todos browsers ( http://caniuse.com/#search=date )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Segue um exemplo utilizando o plugin https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/
Obs.: Input date não são suportados por todos browsers ( http://caniuse.com/#search=date )

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".mask-date").mask('99/99/9999');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/js/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-group col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">        
  <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2 form-label">
    Data Formatada
  </div>         
  <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-10 col-xs-10">            
    <input type='text' class="mask-date" />
  </div>     
</div>
```

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6ys60t20/)